# How do I add an image inside a rectangle or a circle in JavaFX?

Tags: java, 2d, geometry, image

Suppose we have a rectangle called r

```
Rectangle r = new Rectangle(40, 20);
```

and an image called image

```
Image image = new Image("...src for image");
```

How do I fit the image inside the rectangle? Also, how can I make the image move if the rectangle moves too? How do I do the same thing for a circle? Code examples are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

If you absolutely need to use a Rectangle, you can use an [ImagePattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/paint/ImagePattern.html) and set it as the fill for the Rectangle. Only do this if you want the Rectangle for the rounded corners, the ability to have a 'border' (stroke, inherited from Shape), or some other feature of Rectangle. Otherwise, I suggest using an [ImageView](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/image/ImageView.html).

I'm actually trying to figure out the functional difference between these strategies myself, which is how I stumbled upon your post.

```
Image image = new Image("myImage");
Rectangle rekt = new Rectangle(40, 40); //haha
//    ☐ rekt
//    ☐ not rekt
//    ☑ tyrannosaurus rekt 
ImagePattern imagePattern = new ImagePattern(image);
rekt.setFill(imagePattern);

ImageView imageView = new ImageView(image);
```

Answer (score 2):

Wrap your shape in a `StackPane`, along with a `Pane` (or any containing `Node`) for your `Image`. When you need to drag, move, scale, or otherwise alter your component, act on the `StackPane`, this will carry changes over to its children, which are your shape and `Pane`:

```
StackPane pane = new StackPane();
Rectangle r = new Rectangle(50, 50);
r.setFill(Color.RED);
Pane p = new Pane();
p.setStyle("-fx-background-image: url("http://www.bogotobogo.com/images/java/tutorial/java_images/Duke256.png");
    -fx-background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -fx-background-size: contain;");
pane.getChildren().addAll(r, p);
r.widthProperty().bind(pane.prefWidthProperty());
r.heightProperty().bind(pane.prefHeightProperty());
pane.setPrefSize(100, 100);
```

The style set on the `Pane` is what causes your image to be resized to the smallest dimension of the `Pane`. That is, if the smallest dimension is the width, the image will be sized (aspect ratio preserved) so it is precisely large enough to fill the entire width. See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#region) to learn about how to play around with the `-fx-background-size` attribute.

The bindings ensure your shape will be the same size as the `StackPane` at all times, so long as you operate with the preferred dimensions (`setPrefSize(double, double)`) of the `StackPane`.

Note that for the `-fx-background-image` attribute, you specify the URL to your desired image.